# Ref to implementation of Functional Interfaces returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot

Below is the dummy code that is replica of my original problem. I am trying to call a predicate from another service but it is returned as null

```
@Service
public class CommonService {
    public Predicate<Student> isRegistered= student -> {
        boolean isRegistered = // call another service to check

        return isRegistered;
    };
}

@Service
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    CommonService commonService;

    public void processStudentData(Student student){
        if(commonService.isRegistered.test(student){
            // do processing
        }
    }
}
```

commonService.isRegistered is returned as null

Comment: You shoud make `CommonService` a `@Component` as well and refactor `isRegistered` logic to a dedicted service method returning a `boolean` instead of `Predicate`.

Comment: Can you replace direct access to field with getter?

Comment: Try annotating `StudentService` with either `@Component` or `@Service`. Also update your question with the logs.

Comment: @Glains I have updated the code with service annotation. It was already there in my original code, I forgot to add here. Dedicated method will work but I need a Predicate because in original code chaining is required

Comment: @talex getter will work but I need a Predicate because in original code chaining is required

Comment: @ThomasAndolf  I have updated the code with service annotation. It was already there in my original code, I forgot to add here. In logs It is throwing NullPointerException

Comment: I dont want to hear from you what the logs are saying, i want to see the log with a stacktrace. And can you please update your code with the ACTUAL code you are using so we dont have to sit and suggest ”thing you already have”

Comment: @ThomasAndolf 1. Original code is huge 2. I am not allowed to paste original code 3. Code I have pasted here clearly explain the scenario in original code